# Why is the integer variable disappearing in this bash while loop?

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, integer

I'm trying to list an array of directory names using a while loop in a bash script.

The loop code is the following (where $len is the length of $folderArray):

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt $len ]; do
  echo "$i: ${folderArray[$i]}"
  let i++
done
```

However, my output is displayed as follows:

```
0: folder1
folder2
folder3
etc.
```

Why is the "1:" and "2:" not displayed for folder2 and folder3?

I read about using process substitution to solve this but I'm not sure how that would help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shows that you stored all items in one element of an array:

```
"${folderArray[0]}"
```

If you tried to do some word splitting before that, you probably weren't able to split them at all. Consider checking that code that you use to store lines to `folderArray`.

Comment: Or possibly that the other items  start with `\r`, but your explanation is more likely.

Comment: I set it equal to: `ssh -l $remoteUser $remoteHost \"ls $remoteDir\"`

Comment: Use `find` and `readarray` instead: `readarray -t folderArray < <(exec ssh -l "$remoteUser" "$remoteHost" "find \"$remoteDir\" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%f\n'")`

Answer (score 1):

First check what is actually stored in the first element of your `folderArray` array. Most likely this is in `${folderArray[0]}`:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
```

and your `while` loop passes through this in one iteration.

Test this by just saying `echo "${folderArray[0]}"`

In other words: No variable is disappearing. Your loop just has one iteration.

---

Edit: Based on your comment, maybe something like this:

```
folderArray=$(ssh ${remoteUser}@${remoteHost} "ls $remoteDir")
count=0
for f in $folderArray ; do
  echo "$count: $f"
  ((count++))
done
```

Comment: You're right! I tried to put the array of folder names into folderArray using this code: folderArray="`ssh -l $remoteUser $remoteHost \"ls $remoteDir\"`"